# implode users first- and last name. then check with regex

Tags: php, regex

Have a small problem, but hopefully very easy to fix!

I send $user_firstname and $user_lastname with $_POST. Then i try to implode there two to create a username, like this:

```
$arr = array($user_firstname,$user_lastname);
    $user_name  = implode(" ",$arr);
```

Then i want to make sure that the characters is right as well.

When i only had a one line username, this worked fine:

```
(!preg_match('/^[a-z\d]{2,64}$/i', $user_name))
```

But now i want First- & Lastname, and i thought this regex would work:

```
(!preg_match('/^[a-z]+( [a-z]+){2,64}$/i', $user_name))
```

My application gives me the right error, that there is a error with the username.
But i need help with the regex.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: post the error report.

Comment: Does this work? `/^[a-z\d\s]{2,64}$/i`

Comment: Give example strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(!preg_match('/^(?=.{2,64}$)([a-z\d]+\s[a-z\d]+)$/i', $user_name))
```

The lookahead checks the length and then there are two alphanumeric sets with a whitespace seperator.